# transpose, concatenate, stack multiple, identical group of rows

Tags: matrix, row, shapes

groups of rows have to be transposed and then concatenated/stacked.....example suppose I have a 6 by 5 matrix where 6 = rows, appear like 1,2,1,2,1,2 (identical groups of rows) and 5 columns, and I want a matrix 15 by 2 which has 15 rows and 2 columns (constituting the identical groups of rows i.e. 1,2).....trying to do it in python jupyter notebook........visually, the problem can be to change the following

1 2 3 4 5
1 . . . . .
2 . . . . .
1 . . . . .
2 . . . . .
1 . . . . .
2 . . . . .

to

1 2
1  . .
2  . .
3  . .
4  . .
.
.
.
15 . .

I am new to python jupyter programing so don't know how to address this problem